# Spring environment.getProperty not resolving

Tags: java, spring, environment-variables

My java application needs to read a property from an environment varibale, as follows:

```
org.springframework.core.env.getProperty("key", "defaultValue");
```

I have 'key' set in an environment variable. When I run this code locally, key is correctly resolving (from the env variable). But when I deploy my code to an environment, the default value is being picked up. I've checked the spelling and all looks good.

Anyone any experience of this happening?

Comment: Are you sure the environmental variable exists on the environment?

Comment: Are you sure that your variable is set in the deployed environment?

Comment: You can provider the detail debug information when call the `getProperty` method.The spring will output the debug info when find property or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had named by env variable a.b.c when I should have named it a_b_c, which worked.